# What has happened to the IE6 developer toolbar?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, web-developer-toolbar

It's supposed to be at this link:

`http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en`

"Supposed" being the operative word!

Any ideas?

Has Microsoft removed it or accidentally broken the link?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this link 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en

Comment: I know, it's a big shame to look for things like that in 2017, however this link isn't working as well..

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IE8, the dev toolbar is integrated with IE